# How do I set a background image on a running terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal

I don't know if this is possible.  I would like to make cmus use album art as my terminal's background.

I found a number of terminals that can display background images (aterm seems to be the most popular for this kind of bling).  But I can't find a way to switch those images on the fly.  I was hoping there would be a tool like xtermcontrol and that I could find way to target an arbitrary term with it (or run a loop that listens to a fifo...) to set the background image whenever I like.

I have a slight preference for xterm or urxvt, but I don't mind installing whatever terminal supports this functionality.  Any suggestions?

-- edit --

Just tried the stupidest hack I could think of.  aterm in a xephyr with a semi-transparent background.  I could in fact control the background with `DISPLAY=:2.0 feh...` but performance was awful, I couldn't get shading, and my xmonad keybindings and xmodmap config didn't work so well inside the xephyr.  So close!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  There's an escape code you can printf.  "\E]20;file.ext;100\a".  Totally should have guess that.

I'm using 
    while : ; do
      if read line 
      sleep 1
    done

to continually read in new file names from a named pipe.  Alas I don't like the effect after all.  Oh well.  Hopefully someone else finds this useful.  Finished scripts here: https://github.com/sagotsky/.dotfiles/commit/156c781c73617bfe0c2200d443d18bb8cb2e54e2